# List of attributes from class and include module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a class (ActorClue) that has three attr_accessor defined within it.  There are a couple other common fields needed by other classes, so I put those common fields in a module (BaseClueProperties).  I am including that module within my ActorClue class.

Here's the code sampling :

```
module BaseClueProperties  
  attr_accessor :image_url
  attr_accessor :summary_text  
end

################
class BaseClue

  # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487333/fastest-one-liner-way-to-list-attr-accessors in-ruby    
  def self.attr_accessor(*vars)
    @attributes ||= []

    @attributes.concat vars

    super(*vars)
  end

  def self.attributes
    @attributes
  end

  def attributes
    self.class.attributes
  end

end

###############

class ActorClue < BaseClue

  attr_accessor :actor_name
  attr_accessor :movie_name
  attr_accessor :directed_by

  include BaseClueProperties

  .....
end
```

I instantiate the above with the following :

```
>> gg = ActorClue.new
=> #<ActorClue:0x23bf784>
>> gg.attributes
=> [:actor_name, :movie_name, :directed_by]
```

Why is it only returning :actor_name, :movie_name, and :directed_by and not include :image_url and :summary_text?

I modified the BaseClueProperties to read the following :

```
module BaseClueProperties  
  BaseClue.attr_accessor :image_url
  BaseClue.attr_accessor :summary_text  
end
```

But still with the same result.

Any thoughts as to why my :image_url and :summary_text attributes aren't getting added to my @attributes collection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't promise that my description of the reason is correct but the following code should fix the problem. I believe that your are adding attributes to the Module not to the class that it is included within. Anyhow replacing your module with the following should fix the problem.

```
module BaseClueProperties

  def self.included(base)
    base.send :attr_accessor, :image_url
    base.send :attr_accessor, :summary_text
  end

end
```

This should cause the including object to define attribute_accessors when it includes the module.