# How to get attributes that were defined through attr_reader or attr_accessor

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Suppose I have a class `A`

```
class A
  attr_accessor :x, :y

  def initialize(x,y)
    @x, @y = x, y
  end
end
```

How can I get `x` and `y` attributes without knowing how exactly they were named.

E.g.

```
a = A.new(5,10)
a.attributes # => [5, 10]
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use introspection, Luke!

```
class A
  attr_accessor :x, :y

  def initialize(*args)
    @x, @y = args
  end

  def attrs
    instance_variables.map{|ivar| instance_variable_get ivar}
  end
end

a = A.new(5,10)
a.x # => 5
a.y # => 10
a.attrs # => [5, 10]
```

Comment: Note: attrs will return *all* instance variables, rather than just those exposed by `attr_accessor`

Comment: @Jonah: yes, that was the assumption back then. For a more precise method, one can refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34440466/125816).

Answer (score 17):

While Sergio's answer helps, it will return all the instance variables, which if I understand correctly the OP's question, is not what is asked.

If you want to return only the 'attributes' that have e.g. a mutator, you have to do something slightly more complicated such as:

```
attrs = Hash.new
instance_variables.each do |var|
  str = var.to_s.gsub /^@/, ''
  if respond_to? "#{str}="
    attrs[str.to_sym] = instance_variable_get var
  end
end
attrs
```

This returns only the attributes declared with attr_accessor (or with a manually created mutator), and keep the internal instance variables hidden. You can do something similar if you want the ones declared with attr_reader.

Comment: I think this is a better answer given the question. I'll just append on to it.

Ruby creates {Variable}= methods whenever a symbol has been added as an accessor or writer. respond_to? just ensures that there is a valid method that exist with the {Variable}= name. The first part is to chomp off the first "@" on the returned variable.

In the OP example, methods "x=" and "y=" will get created, and you're looking for them with @x;x= and @y;y=

Comment: In some instances, this will include `:attributes=`. :/

Answer (score 15):

```
class A
  ATTRIBUTES = [:x, :y]
  attr_accessor *ATTRIBUTES

  def initialize(x,y)
    @x, @y = x, y
  end

  def attributes
    ATTRIBUTES.map{|attribute| self.send(attribute) }
  end
end
```

This may not be the DRY-est, but if you are only concerned with doing this for one class (as opposed to a base class that everything inherits from), then this should work.

Comment: The best answer!

Answer (score 3):

See this other [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487333/fastest-one-liner-way-to-list-attr-accessors-in-ruby). They override `attr_accessor`.

```
  def self.attr_accessor(*vars)
    @attributes ||= []
    @attributes.concat vars
    super(*vars)
  end

  def self.attributes
    @attributes
  end

  def attributes
    self.class.attributes
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have `attr_writer`s/`attr_accessor`s defined on your attributes, than they can be easily retrieved by matching the `=$` regexp:

```
A.instance_methods.each_with_object([]) { |key, acc| acc << key.to_s.gsub(/=$/, '') if key.match(/\w=$/) }
```

OR

```
A.instance_methods.each_with_object([]) { |key, acc| acc << key if key = key.to_s.match(/^(.*\w)=$/)&.[](1) }
```

Answer (score 1):

when you use attr_accessor to define attributes in a class, Ruby using refexion, define a couple of methods, for each attribute declared, one to get the value and other to set, an instance variable of the same name of the attribute

you can see this methods using

```
p A.instance_methods

[:x, :x=, :y, :y=, :nil?, :===, :=~, :!~, :eql?, :hash, :<=>, :class, :singleton_class, :clone, :dup, :initialize_dup, :initialize_clone, :taint, :tainted?, :untaint, :untrust, :untrusted?,..
```

So this attributes are accesible, outside the class, with

```
p "#{a.x},#{a.y}"
```

or inside the class through the corresponding instance variable

```
class A
  ...
  def attributes
    [@x,@y]
  end
  ...
end
p a.attributes   #=> [5,10]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I asked about a case when I don't know the names of the attributes, because otherwise it wouldn't be DRY approach. For example, what if I decide to add additional attributes `@d`, `@e`, `@f`. Then I'll have to add them in `attributes` method manualy as well as in `initialize`, which leads to the duplication of code.

Comment: In this situation,  use the Sergio's solution