# Get attr_accessor/instance variables in ruby

Tags: ruby, attributes, instance-variables

So I know that you can get all instance variables in Ruby by calling `#instance_variables`, but if they haven't yet been set then they don't show up.

**Example**

```
class Walrus
  attr_accessor :flippers, :tusks
end

w = Walrus.new
w.instance_variables # => []
w.tusks              # => nil
w.instance_variables # => [:@tusks]
```

I want to access all of the instance variables defined by attr_accessor immediately.

```
w = Walrus.new
w.instance_variables # => [:@tusks, :@flippers]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get attributes that were defined through attr\_reader or attr\_accessor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006889/how-to-get-attributes-that-were-defined-through-attr-reader-or-attr-accessor)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, they don't yet exist. Instance variables spring into existence upon first assignment. If you want them in a brand new instance, then touch them in the constructor.

```
class Walrus
  attr_accessor :flippers, :tusks

  def initialize
    self.flippers = self.tusks = nil
  end
end

w = Walrus.new
w.instance_variables # => [:@tusks, :@flippers]
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, `attr_accessor` creates a pair of methods, a setter and a getter. I'm not sure if there's a built-in way to get a list, but you could look through the instance methods for the resulting pairs:

```
Walrus.instance_methods.find_all do |method|
  method != :== &&
  method != :! &&
  Walrus.instance_methods.include?(:"#{method}=")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using methods minus the methods from Object or Class?  the returning array will contain your defined attributes/methods, and the instance variables defined in getter/accessor.

```
your_instance_name.methods - Object.methods
your_instance_name.methods - Class.methods
```