# Map from one object to another in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two objects, a **UserData** object and a **User** object. At the moment they look like this:

**user_data.rb**

```
class UserData < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table = "users"
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User
  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password
end
```

What I'm trying to do now is map the **UserData** object to the **User** object and the other way around. For the first scenario I have the following code:

```
module Mappers
  module UserMapper
   def map user
     @user = UserData.new
     @user.first_name = user.first_name
     @user.last_name = user.last_name
     @user.password = user.password
     @user.email = user.email
   end
  end
end
```

However, the problem is that whenever I add a new column to the users table, I have to add the code in the mapper as well. And when I have tons of objects inside my code that need to be mapped, it's going to be really messy. My question is: **Is there a better / dynamic way for doing this?** The ideal situation would be when I don't have to touch the Mapper code anymore.

Comment: Why don't you inherit your `User` class from `ActiveRecord::Base`. Why do you want to keep two separate classes and map the attributes?

Comment: I want to isolate my data models and and don't be aware of the existence of Active Record anywhere inside my application, besides the data models itself.

Comment: The data should be kept with the model. That why they exist. If you want to keep the logic isolated, I would suggest using service layer in your application. But keep the data where it actually belongs. For reference, you could read [this article](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a list of attribute names from an ActiveRecord model by calling the `attribute_names` class method. Armed with that, it's easy to iterate over them and fetch and assign each attribute in turn:

```
module UserMapper
  def map(user)
    @user = UserData.new do |user_data|
      UserData.attribute_names.each do |attr_name|
        next unless user.respond_to?(attr_name)
        user_data[attr_name] = user.public_send(attr_name)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You could use the same method to dynamically create `attr_accessor`s in your User class, if you wanted:

```
class User
  attr_accessor *UserData.attribute_names
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a bit ruby meta programming to complete this:

```
class User
  ATTRS = [:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password]
  attr_accessor *ATTRS
end

module Mappers
  module UserMapper
   def map(user)
     @user = UserData.new
     User::ATTRS.each do |attr|
       @user.send("#{attr}=", user.send(attr))
     end
   end
  end
end
```

Then you just modify `ATTRS` and everything will work automatically!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something based on this question: [Fastest/One-liner way to list attr_accessors in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487333/fastest-one-liner-way-to-list-attr-accessors-in-ruby)

```
module Mappers
  module UserMapper
    def map user
      @user = UserData.new
      user.attributes.inspect.each do |attr|
        @user.public_send("#{attr}=", user.public_send(attr))
      end
    end
  end
end
```