# Get fields from Ruby Model belonging to a certain Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

How do I get from a Ruby model all attributes or column_names which belong to a certain class (that is, which have a certain column type in the database)?

```
E.g.:
-Get all column_names belonging to class ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone from following Model having fields:
:id
:order_id String
:slot_id Integer
:delivery_date TimeWithZone
:packed_date TimeWithZone
:created_at TimeWithZone
:updated_at TimeWithZone

-Output:
['created_at','updated_at','delivery_date','packed_date']
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest/One-liner way to list attr\_accessors in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487333/fastest-one-liner-way-to-list-attr-accessors-in-ruby)

Comment: I don't think this is a proper duplicate of the nominated examplar: That question asks how to find all accessor method defined with attr_accessor.  This question asks how to find all accessor methods for columns which map to a certain type of column.

Comment: I've made an edit that I hope makes the question more clear.  If I have erred, please roll back my edit.

Comment: Thanks for edit @WayneConrad as it's more relevant, yes as exactly pointed out, this question is different from finding all accessor methods defined with attr_accessor.

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 4 with Postgres you could try this:

```
ModelName.columns.select {|col| col.sql_type == "timestamp with time zone" }.map(&:name)
```

For Rails 3 with MySQL you could try this:

```
ModelName.arel_table.columns.select {|col| col.class == Arel::Attributes::Time }.map(&:name)
```